# React+Konva: How to fillPatternImage with uploaded image?

Tags: konvajs, react-konva

Following code (from images on imgur) in fillPatternImage works:

```
var url = "http://www.imgur....." 
var newImage = new window.Image(); 
newImage.src = url;
```

then I find ref to the shape I want to change and I use `setAttr("fillPatternImage", image)` and it the pattern shows in my shape

But when I do:

```
<input type="file" ...blah blah ... onClick={(event) => {
   var url = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]; 
   let newImage = new window.Image()
   newImage.src = url
 }}
```

and then do the whole `setAttr` thing, it wouldn't work. I am sure the source is valid in that if I make a new state called imageUrl with url from the uploaded image and do: `<img src={this.state.imageUrl}`, the image shows perfectly.

**Only difference between the 2 srcs:**

- source from the direct imgur source is just the link to the image, for example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPxZX.png

[image: image taken from https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPxZX.png]

- source from the uploaded image is "blob:http://localhost:3000/c0e5194d-1c58-4aa1-b4d6-6abf7438e179"

By the way, importing image file from the public folder and then setting it as the src of a native javascript image then fillPatternImage with that image also worked.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `URL.createObjectURL` you can use base64 URL of the file:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
reader.onload = function () {
  var newImage = new window.Image()
  newImage.src = reader.result
};
```

Comment: Hi Lavrton, first of all thank you for writing Konva. I still have no luck with this solution, after setAttr fillPatternImage with image created with your way it still turns black. If I do console.log(the image I fillPatternImage with) I see its src being a long (44.6KB) string. Is there perhaps another way to do this? Or is there some way to varify if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Trying to open that very long src in new tab. You should see the image.